# How to mock `TResult DefaultsTo Document` in scala

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, unit-testing

I am working on a unit test for a small proxy class to scala mondo driver.
One of the methods I have is getting connection by name from database object:

```
def collection(collectionName: String): MongoCollection[Document] = {
    logger.info("Getting collection " + collectionName)
    defaultDB.getCollection[Document](collectionName)
  }
```

where `defaultDB` is an instance of `MongoDatabase` class.

In my test, I want to mock the method `getCollection` of of `MongoDatabase` class, like so:

```
val collection = mock[MongoCollection[Document]]

val database = mock[MongoDatabase]
when(database.getCollection[Document]("collection")).thenReturn(collection)
```

This, of coarse, will return nothing, since the real signature looks like this:

```
def getCollection[TResult](collectionName: String)(implicit e: TResult DefaultsTo Document, ct: ClassTag[TResult]): MongoCollection[TResult]
```

So, we tried mocking the other two implicit arguments:

```
implicit val e = mock[Document DefaultsTo org.mongodb.scala.Document]
      implicit val classTag = mock[ClassTag[Document]]

      val collection = mock[MongoCollection[Document]]

      val database = mock[MongoDatabase]("collection")(e, _: ClassTag[Document])
      when(database.getCollection[Document]("collection")(e, classTag)).thenReturn(collection)
```

And now, i am getting the following error:

> [error]  Access to protected object DefaultHelper not permitted
>   because [error]  enclosing package mongo is not a subclass of [error] 
>   package bson in package scala where target is defined [error] import
>   org.mongodb.scala.bson.DefaultHelper.DefaultsTo [error]
>   ^ [error] /app/process-street/test/mongo/MongoDriverSpec.scala:61: not
>   found: type DefaultsTo [error]       implicit val e = mock[Document
>   DefaultsTo org.mongodb.scala.Document]

And in fact, `DefaultHelper` is protected...
Is there any way around this? What are my other options to mock `getConnection` method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and this worked for me:

```
when(database.getCollection[Document](any)(any, any)).thenReturn(collection)
```